# Iconography for a "Pokemon moves list"?

Tags: icon, applications

I've been trying to find an icon that represents a Pokémon moves list for an app I'm developing, mind you this is an Android app and the icon will go directly to the ActionBar on a opaque background so it will have to be completely white and really simple, I've thought of a boxing glove of some sort or crossing swords, and I'm leaning towards the glove but I'm not totally convinced, in the games there usually no icon relating to moves other than the ones that represent if the move is physical or special.

Comment: Hi Eddnav, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you please clarify a little for those amongst us who -- gasp! :) -- have never played Pokémon? I *am* a video gamer, but I have no clue what you're trying to make an icon for. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Vincent, you see, I'm trying to make an icon for a link that opens a window where a list of Pokemon moves (attacks or spells if you will) is shown with their different parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

[image]

But adding a pokeball...

Comment: This is brilliant, it certainly conveys a Pokémon move.

Answer (score 0):

The most recognizable thing in the poké universe is the poké ball, and the start of every poké battle is throwing the poké ball.

As an icon, how about a poké ball popping open? Something like an iconographic version of this?

[image: Pokeball opening]